# How can I instruct R to left justify the text in a character column when displaying a data.table?

Tags: r, printing, data.table, justify

How can I instruct [R](https://www.r-project.org/) to left justify the text in a character column when displaying a [data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/)?

For example, how might I instruct R to left justify column "text" in the following output so that it matches the desired output?

```r
library(data.table)
(data1 <- data.table(text = c("AAAAAA", "B", "C"), number = c(1, 2, 3)))
#>      text number
#> 1: AAAAAA      1
#> 2:      B      2
#> 3:      C      3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Desired output:

```r
#>    text   number
#> 1: AAAAAA      1
#> 2: B           2
#> 3: C           3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass `justify = "left"` argument to `print.data.table`:

```
print(data1,justify="left")
     text number
   <char>  <num>
1: AAAAAA      1
2: B           2
3: C           3
```